# Make page only visitable after visiting previous page

Tags: php

I'm very new to PHP and am creating a php contact page. Upon filling the form, you are redirected to success.php (note the contact page is index.php). I want success.php only visitable if you came from index.php. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Learn about sessions, but before that, learn about what kind of questions are asked in this site

Answer (score 1):

On a second thought, You can use PHP's Server variable called `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` to check from which page a user is comming from. For example, If you have `index.php` and `contact.php` then, if you place  `echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];` in `contact.php`, everytime you visit that page, it will tell you from which page you are coming from.

So, in you case, if you wanted people to go to `success.php` after ONLY filing `contact.php` then you can place this in the success page.

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == 'contact.php') {
echo 'Success';
}else {echo 'Please go back to contact page first';}
```

You can learn more about `$_SERVER[]` variables, here php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php